# How do I render a cms/blocks collection into attribute list from product tab Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, cms-block, renderer

I have create an attribute and I want to render an cms blocks as attribute values in Magento 2. Please do provide some go on it and I have done research about it but no clue so far.
Thanks.

Comment: Refer [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/206612) link.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but What I want is from admin product create section, I want to render all the cms blocks which the store has...I mean source to get all the collection from product attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

namespace Commerceshop\Artifex\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup; 
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory /* For Attribute create  */;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory; 
    /* assign object to class global variable for use in other class methods */
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
    /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    /**
     * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
     */
    $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,'custom_product_tab');
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'custom_product_tab',/* Custom Attribute Code */
        [
            'group' => 'Product Details',/* Group name in which you want 
                                          to display your custom attribute */
            'type' => 'text',/* Data type in which formate your value save in database*/
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Custom Product Tab', /* lablel of your attribute*/
            'input' => 'select',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => 'Commerceshop\Artifex\Model\Config\Source\Options',
                            /* Source of your select type custom attribute options*/
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                                /*Scope of your attribute */
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => true,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false
        ]
    );
    }
}
```

In source file you just need to have cms/block collection as follows.

```
<?php

namespace Commerceshop\Artifex\Model\Config\Source;

use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\OptionFactory; 
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table; 

class Options extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource 
{ 
    /** 
     * Get all options 
     * 
     * @return array 
     */ 
    public function getAllOptions() 
    { 

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection();
    $tableName = $resource->getTableName('cms_block');
    $sql = $connection->select()->from(
             ["tn" => $tableName]
        );
    if(!$this->_options)
    {
        $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
                     $this->_options = array(
                    array(
                            'value' => '',
                            'label' => '',
                    )
            );
        $this->_options=[ ['label'=>'Select Options', 'value'=>'']];
        foreach($result as $s)
        {
            $this->_options[] = array('value' => $s['identifier'], 'label' => $s['title']);
        }
    }
    return $this->_options;
    }

    /**
     * Get a text for option value
     *
     * @param string|integer $value
     * @return string|bool
     */
    public function getOptionText($value)
    {
    foreach ($this->getAllOptions() as $option) {
        if ($option['value'] == $value) {
            return $option['label'];
        }
    }
    return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UpgradeData.php example with new catalog product EAV attribute with a source model as a Block list.

**There is a native source module available for it:**

```
'source' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Page::class,
```

**Full UpgradeData script:**

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\Catalog\Setup;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     */
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.0', '<')) {
            $this->installAdditionCmsBlockAttribute($setup);
        }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @return void
     */
    public function installAdditionCmsBlockAttribute(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            ProductAttributeInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CODE,
            'product_additional_cms_content',
            [
                'label' => 'Additional CMS Content',
                'type' => 'int',
                'input' => 'select',
                'visible' => true,
                'source' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Page::class,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'required' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => 1,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'sort_order' => 100
            ]
        );
    }
}
```